# Integrate jsf and jsp with spring mvc in same project

Tags: spring, jsp, jsf, spring-mvc

Can we integrate jsf and jsp with spring mvc in same project???

if the request ends with .jsf or .xhtml ---->it has to be handled by
faces servlet and

if the request ends with .jsp ---->should be handled by dispatcher servlet.

If i'm anything wrong please advice me the correct way because i'm  newbie to spring mvc...

this is my web.xml file

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>profile.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Face Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Face Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

is this possible or anything wrong???

Comment: Is this for a new project, or are you trying to retrofit existing code?

Comment: for a new project.... im trying to handle the jsp request directly by spring controller instead of face servlet...

Comment: For new projects, JSF is a bad idea. It has all sorts of state problems that lead to interaction bugs and difficulty with scaling and session management. I strongly recommend using straight JSP or Thymeleaf instead.

Comment: thanks...@tiny i understood that...but what my query was can we use faceservlet and dispatcher servlet in the same project????(Face servlet for handling the url ending with .jsf or .xhtml and DispatcherServlet for url end with .jsp or something like /ser)

Comment: thanks for your advice @chrylis i'll probably search on that....

Comment: Can you tell me that stupid tricks @tiny